# Excel VBA to save to specific folder (with current code generating filename)

Tags: vba, excel

workers,

I have this code at the moment;

```
Public Sub SaveAsA1()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("P4").Value & ";" & Range("F6").Value & ";" & Range("R6").Value & ";" & Range("R4").Value
End Sub
```

Which i would like to modify to be saved in a certain filemap; \S31000265\Users$\NR4236\My Documents\TV-01-project\TestmapWeek9GOED. Been trying but it keeps overwriting the Filename-code. Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: whats the values of  P4, F6, R6 and R4 ?

Comment: The values are text, which i use to generate file names based upon employee number, employee name, etc. Values are variable at all times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Sub SaveAsA1()
    ChDir ("C:\work\testout\") ' Directory you need to save the file as xlsm
    Filename = Range("P4").Value & ";" & Range("F6").Value & ";" & Range("R6").Value & ";" & Range("R4").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Filename, FileFormat:=52
End Sub
```

Comment: A real hero to me man! Your code runs smooth as it should. Thank you so much!

Comment: @RobExcel, Welcome